# Play Store Purchased Apps

Tags: google-play-store

I've kind of a dumb question. I've recently purchased an app from play store. I've not installed it yet, but I notice that there is a remove option for it. My question if I remove it, do I have to purchase it again or is it only removed from my apps list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I re-install a purchased app from Google's Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4187/can-i-re-install-a-purchased-app-from-googles-play-store)

Comment: I'm not asking about reinstalling the app in the phone. I'm asking about the remove app from my apps list option in the play store. If i remove it from there, should i purchase it again. Why is there a remove option at all for the purchased apps.

Comment: Basically, the answer is the same: unless you ask for refund, everything you do won't invalidate the purchase. "My apps" can be considered as a history of your Play Store transaction.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. How will you find that particular app again, once you have removed it from My Apps?

Comment: You can check it on Play Store's [My Orders](https://play.google.com/store/account) or browser version of [My apps](https://play.google.com/apps) (maybe [related](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66421/play-store-my-app-section?rq=1))

Comment: Thank you again. And i just tried it. I remove the app from my apps and searched for it. It still says purchased. Also i found an app called purchased apps. That's useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you purchase an app you don't have to purchase it again unless you switch Google accounts.

Comment: Even if I remove it from my apps list?